# mysql table column datatype medium int not working

Tags: mysql, integer

I have problem with one of my mysql table datatype. In that table i have a column stokid, for this i gave data type as medium int.It works fine with upto this number 8141114 i mean when i run a insert query it inserts corrctly. But when i try to run a

insert query with 9041214 this number i am getting some different number in that column --- 8388607

After that i changed that column type as int . Now its working fine. But when it was medium int why it was not worked? Can some one please clarify this one?

Comment: So you were able to fix it, but you weren't able to determine why? And word `medium` didn't hint that there *might* be something to do with the actual length of the number? Common sense is indeed a super freakin' power.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html); `MEDIUMINT` has a maximum value of `8388607` *signed*. Alter the type to `INT` for a higher maximum value.